# Best Approach to Collect Facebook Post data from Research Participants

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with a research group that needs to collect Facebook post data for a group of participants over the course of a few months.  The goal is let the participants authorize us to collect this information via facebook, and when they post to Facebook, send that information to a secured server.

After reading the Facebook documentation, I'm mostly just confused about how to provide a mechanism for the user to agree to the terms of collecting his/her data.  I'm planning on using webhooks to collect the data, which is independent of the client platform, but do I really need to build separate apps for web, iOS and Android just for the approval process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm planning on using webhooks to collect the data, which is independent of the client platform, but do I really need to build separate apps for web, iOS and Android just for the approval process?

You most likely won't get this approved in review anyway.

Permissions must, for the most part, be used to provide a direct benefit to the in-app user experience; collecting data for analytical measures only is explicitly mentioned as a not allowed use case. Whether the users would agree is not relevant here.

For example, [`user_posts`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_posts) permission, has *"non-visible use of this data such as sentiment analysis or guarding against spam bots"* marked with a red "X" for *nope*.

So the only way of getting your app to request the necessary permission(s) from users, would be to add them as testers to the app via app dashboard/API. Anyone with a role in the app which can be asked for any permission, reviewed or not. Those users would however have to have their accounts verified (mobile/text, credit card) and sign up as a "developer" on the FB platform, before your app could send them requests to become testers.

You'd be flying under the radar with that, so to speak. Facebook offers this "loophole" mainly for the purpose of letting developers test and develop their apps properly, before review. It is also explicitly mentioned in the app development FAQ as a way around the need for review, for specific use cases such as wanting to get your blog posts published to your own FB page automatically. It would not cover what you are trying to do so, but it will likely "work" as long as none of your test users specifically raises a complaint with Facebook ...

Not sure if there is any published limit on the number of test users that can be added to an app, people have asked about that in the past, but AFAIK none is documented or otherwise published by Facebook. If there is one, and it is not completely stopping this approach dead in it's tracks (say, a few hundred per app rather than, five), you could use multiple app ids, *if* you don't need to relate data between user accounts too much - because the app-scoped user ids will be different per app id, so that could making connections between friends that are in different "app-id test groups" etc. difficult. Or you might have to refer to other, less reliable measures of uniquely identifying them, such as email or profile name.

Comment: By the way, it looks like the max test users right now is 2000, according to the [Test Users Rules](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#rules).

Comment: @foundling cool, didn't know they are giving a specific number now.